# How to select text using xpath with selenium in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I need to scrape the text of the company overview section of a page as captured below:
[image: snapshot of web elements to scrape]

this is my attempt here:
[image: my attempt on jupyter notebook]

But it doesn't extract the text. Please how do I go about it?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it can be shared in public?

Comment: I am trying to scrap glassdoor https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword=data-science&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0

Answer (score 1):

**Change your XPath expressions as below:**

```
//span[text()='Size']//following-sibling::span
//span[text()='Founded']//following-sibling::span
//span[text()='Type']//following-sibling::span
```

**Refer the working code below:**

```
URL = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword=data-science&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0"
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept Cookies']"))).click()

size = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Size']//following-sibling::span")))
founded = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Founded']//following-sibling::span")))
type = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Type']//following-sibling::span")))

print(size.text)
print(founded.text)
print(type.text)
```

**Console result:**

```
10000+ Employees
1887
Company - Public

Process finished with exit code 0
```